# Passar parametros no R em uma api com o metodo Post?

Tags: r, api, post

Amigos , criei uma api em R usando Plumber com o método post. mas na hora de chamar esta api e passar os parâmetros não estou conseguindo , chamo desta forma:

```
resp <- POST("http:url", body = list(datainicio = '2018-07-23' , datafim = '2018-07-24'), encode = 'json')
r1 <- httr::content(resp, 'text')
```

e o erro retornado é :

> [1] "{\"error\":[\"404 - Resource Not Found\"]}".

Obrigado

Comment: Esse erro em geral não quer dizer que você está passando os dados do jeito errado, e sim que o endpoint não foi encontrado.

Comment: Obrigado  @DanielFalbel . Você tem razão. Depois descobri que existiam firewalls impedido a transação.